# Anything in bios that would prevent one from being able to install from usb to usb?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, usb-flash-drive

I have a gen 8 x1 yoga work computer (its my employers) that I occasionally want to use for personal things but obviously not on the work install (windows). On previous laptops I have been able to install Linux from an "install flash drive" to another usb flash drive and then boot from the "another usb flash drive" - the install was painfully slow but after that the setup worked pretty well (I didnt use the "personal install" regularly, mainly when traveling).

Problem is, doing this isnt working on this laptop? I can write boot media to a flash and then boot from it no problem, but I can't seem to install to a flash and then boot from it. I can't figure out why this is, is there perhaps something in the bios that might affect this?

Comment: Please explain the strange distinction you are making between being able to write "boot media" but not "install". Some Linux .iso files are meant only to be used as installers to some hard disk, but many are full-featured live OS installations. There is no difference in the writing or booting process to create them.

Comment: Sorry, in short. If I write an ISO to a flash, like say ubuntu - its bootable. If i use that bootable flash to install ubuntu to another external drive/flash it installs, but is not bootable